# Origin of $\mapsto$ notation

Tags: notation, math-history

Who invented the brilliant $\mapsto$ notation for describing a function's action on a point, as in $x \mapsto x^2$?

This is in some sense a counterpart to [Who came up with the arrow notation $x \rightarrow y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144821/who-came-up-with-the-arrow-notation-x-rightarrow-y)

Comment: It could have only been [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Arrow)

Comment: And further, why do both it and lambda expressions exist?

Comment: I guess it was Bourbaki but I can't find a reference right now.

Comment: @lhf: thanks! I'm not sure what the appropriate thing to do with this question is now that it's answered on another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $\mapsto$ was introduced by Bourbaki between 1963 and 1964.

HSM has a [full answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/when-was-the-function-arrow-notation-x-mapsto-y-first-used).